# Connection errors setting up SSL in Kafka cluster

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I am trying to set up SSL in my 3 node Kafka cluster, but keep running into connection errors, specifically indicating the brokers can't connect to each other. They are of the form:

```
WARN [Controller-1003-to-broker-1002-send-thread], Controller 1003's connection to broker FQDN:9093 (id: 1002 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
```

I am trying to follow the steps found here (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security) but I admit I've never worked with keystores or certificates so I might well be doing something basic wrong. Here are the settings I've changed in all 3 server.properties file:

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
listeners=SSL://<FQDN>:9093 #Turning off PLAINTEXT to be sure everything is working over SSL
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.key.password=test1234
ssl.keystore.location=/var/private/ssl/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
```

And here are the commands I'm running on each Kafka broker:

```
PASSWORD=test1234
VALIDITY=365
FQDN=`hostname --fqdn`

keytool -alias localhost -keystore server.keystore.jks -keypass $PASSWORD -storepass $PASSWORD -genkeypair  -validity $VALIDITY -dname "cn=$FQDN, ou=development, o=mycom.com, l=stl, st=mo, c=jv" -keyalg RSA

openssl req -new -x509 -keyout ca-key -out ca-cert -days $VALIDITY 
keytool -keystore server.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass test1t34 -noprompt
keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass $PASSWORD -noprompt

keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -certreq -file cert-file -storepass $PASSWORD
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in cert-file -out cert-signed -days $VALIDITY -CAcreateserial -passin pass:$PASSWORD
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass $PASSWORD -noprompt
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -import -file cert-signed -storepass $PASSWORD -noprompt

cp ./server.truststore.jks /var/private/ssl/server.truststore.jks
cp ./server.keystore.jks /var/private/ssl/server.keystore.jks
```

At the end of these commands, each broker has its own local server.truststore.jks and server.keystore.jks, which has not interacted with any of the other brokers.

I have verified port 9093 is open and accessible via telnet (telnet localIP 9093 works fine), but when I run

```
openssl s_client -debug -connect <local IPs>:9093 -tls1
```

all 3 machines return

```
Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

Should I be running all of the above commands on all 3 brokers? Some of the commands reference client.keystore.jks and client.truststore.jks instead.

Does anyone know what is not set up correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I generate CA on one node and then copy to all nodes

Run on all nodes:

```
keytool -alias localhost -keystore server.keystore.jks -keypass $PASSWORD -storepass $PASSWORD -genkeypair  -validity $VALIDITY -dname "cn=$FQDN, ou=development, o=mycom.com, l=stl, st=mo, c=jv" -keyalg RSA
```

On one or local:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout ca-key -out ca-cert -days $VALIDITY
```

**Copy CA to all Nodes**

On all nodes:

```
keytool -keystore server.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass test1t34 -noprompt
```

Client run on one node, then copy to client:

```
keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass $PASSWORD -noprompt
```

On all nodes:

```
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -certreq -file cert-file -storepass $PASSWORD

openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in cert-file -out cert-signed -days $VALIDITY -CAcreateserial -passin pass:$PASSWORD

keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass $PASSWORD -noprompt

keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -import -file cert-signed -storepass $PASSWORD -noprompt

cp ./server.truststore.jks /var/private/ssl/server.truststore.jks

cp ./server.keystore.jks /var/private/ssl/server.keystore.jks
```

Comment: Your steps produce the same error (i.e. Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)